# How to remove Grants component

Tags: civigrant

I have a site with the Grants component that it does not need.
I could not find where to disable it.

Is there a way to remove the Grants component?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a recent version of CiviCRM...

The Grants component comes with CiviCRM but you can do the following:

- if you navigate to Administer>System Settings>Extensions you should see an extension called CiviGrant. You can disable this extension
- to remove the option Grants from your menu, navigate to Administer>Customize Data and Screens>Navivation Menu. Then right-click on the Grants item, you should get a **delete** option. This will just remove the menu item from your menu

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer - a question: the CiviGrant extension is installed and present in the native extensions list in a state where there is only link says 'Install'. There is no Enable and Uninstall links as there is for CiviPledge for example.  How then does one remove CiviGrant?  There are some reports that CiviGrant must be removed for Mosaico email extension to install properly.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/13915)

Comment: CiviGrant is a core extension so can't be removed entirely. I'm not aware that there are any issues with Mosaico and don't think you need to remove CiviGrant for Mosaico to work. If there are issues, then I would suggest submitting a bug report.

Comment: On https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 (ie bleeding edge). it shows an option to Disable. Once disabled I then see options for Enable or Uninstall. If I uninstall then i see the option to Install